# Difficulty with using virtualenv and specific Python version?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to understand how to create an isolated python environment using an alternative version of Python other than the default (in my case this is Python 2.7). `virtualenv` works on my system with Python 2.7, but I can't seem to create a virtual environment with a version of Python 3.

I tried to specify the Python version as outlined in this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv), like this:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.2
```

Can anyone explain how I can create a `virtualenv` with a specific version of Python? Thanks very much.

Comment: What errors did you see?

Comment: The error I got was: `The executable /usr/bin/python3.2 (from --python=/usr/bin/python3.2) does not exist`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need to install python 3.2 to the system first. You're telling the virtualenvironment to use a version of python that doesn't exist anywhere so it cannot find it. This is the "does not exist"

Edit after more info was given in comment:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Perhaps I don't understand. I have Python 3.2 installed at: `/usr/local/bin/python3.2` Why can't it find it?

Comment: @dr.bunsen: In your question, you used `/usr/bin/` instead of `/usr/local/bin/`. Typo or simple solution?

Comment: Try using that path in your `virtualenv -p` command instead of `/usr/bin/python3.2`

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I didn't see that in fact usr/local/bin and usr/bin were in fact different paths. Thanks.